# Keep posting as myself to my page through graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

So I'm trying to post to my page as my page through the [facebook graph exploration tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). I've given myself:

public_profile, manage_pages, publish_actions

and I type in {Page-id}(I'm using the club name used in the url when visiting the page normally)/feed

I pass in: message | Test through POST. However the post appears in Posts To This Page as me instead of in status as my page.

Comment: please search with google and on stackoverflow, there are plenty of threads about how to post "as page" already.

Comment: And they all say to get manage_pages, publish_actions and post to page-id/feed. I've done all that.

Comment: they also say that you must use a page access token. you´ve clearly not done that.

Comment: oh well, let me create an answer, to keep the answer rate on stackoverflow up ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider reading the following articles about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Right now you are obviously posting with a User Token, but you need to use a Page Token in order to post "as Page". You create a Page Token by calling `/me/accounts` after authorizing with `manage_pages` and `publish_actions`. You will get a list of all Pages the User is Admin of, including a Page Token for each one of them.